# simplify splitting a dataframe to several dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have some dataframes (**df0**, **df1**, **df2**) with various numbers of rows. I wanted to split any dataframe which has a number of rows more than 30 to several dataframes consists of 30 rows only. So for example my dataframe **df0** has 156 rows, then I would separated this dataframe into several dataframes like this:

```
if len(df0) > 30:
        df0_A = df0[0:30]
        df0_B = df0[31:60]
        df0_C = df0[61:90]
        df0_D = df0[91:120]
        df0_E = df0[121:150]
        df0_F = df0[151:180]
    else:
        df0= df0
```

The problem with this code is that I need to repeat the code exhaustively many times for the next code like this:

```
df0= pd.DataFrame(df0)
df0_A = pd.DataFrame(df0_A)
df0_B = pd.DataFrame(df0_B)
df0_C = pd.DataFrame(df0_C)
df0_D = pd.DataFrame(df0_D)
df0_E = pd.DataFrame(df0_E)
df0_F = pd.DataFrame(df0_F)

df0= df0.to_string(header=False,
                              index=False,
                              index_names=False).split('\n')
df0_A = df0_A.to_string(header=False,
                              index=False,
                              index_names=False).split('\n')
df0_B = df0_B.to_string(header=False,
                              index=False,
                              index_names=False).split('\n')
df0_C = df0_C.to_string(header=False,
                              index=False,
                              index_names=False).split('\n')
df0_D = df0_D.to_string(header=False,
                              index=False,
                              index_names=False).split('\n')
df0_E = df0_E.to_string(header=False,
                              index=False,
                              index_names=False).split('\n')
df0_F = idUGS0_F.to_string(header=False,
                              index=False,
                              index_names=False).split('\n')

df0= [','.join(ele.split()) for ele in df0]
df0_A = [','.join(ele.split()) for ele in df0_A]
df0_B = [','.join(ele.split()) for ele in df0_B]
df0_C = [','.join(ele.split()) for ele in df0_C]
df0_D = [','.join(ele.split()) for ele in df0_D]
df0_E = [','.join(ele.split()) for ele in df0_E]
df0_F = [','.join(ele.split()) for ele in df0_F]
```

now imagine I have ten dataframes that I need to split each into five dataframes. Then I need to make the same code for 50 times!
I'm quite new to Python. So, can anyone help me with how to simplify this code, maybe with simple *for loop*? thanks

Comment: do you have any sample data?

Comment: @DavidErickson the data of each row is simple numbers of identification code. the thing is that I need to separate these rows of identification code into several dataframes where every dataframe does not exceed more than 30 identification code per dataframe

Comment: Would it not make sense to create a list of dataframes that were split from df0 instead of naming each individual one? Then you can split the dataframes and do whatever you'd like with them within for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably automate it a little bit more, but this should be enough!

```
import copy
import numpy as np
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'Test' : np.random.randint(100000,999999,size=180)})
len(df0)
if len(df0) > 30:
    df_dict = {}
    x=0
    y=30
    for df_letter in ['A','B','C','D','E','F']:
        df_name = f'df0_{df_letter}'    
        df_dict[df_name] = copy.deepcopy(df_letter)
        df_dict[df_name] = pd.DataFrame(df0[x:y]).to_string(header=False, index=False, index_names=False).split('\n ')
        df_dict[df_name] = [','.join(ele.split()) for ele in df_dict[df_name]]
        x += 30
        y += 30
    df_name
else:
    df0
for df in df_dict:
    print(df)
    print('--------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print(f'length: {len(df_dict[df])}')
    print('--------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print(df_dict[df])
    print('--------------------------------------------------------------------')
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have one column for **identification**,

```py
def split_df(idf, idcol, nsize):
  g = idf.groupby(idcol)
  # Compute the size for each value of identification column
  size = g.size()

  dflist = []
  for _id,_idcount in size.iteritems():
    if _idcount > nsize:
      # print(_id, ' = ', _idcount)
      idx     = idf[ idf[idcol].eq(_id) ].index
      # print(idx)
      # lets split the array into equal parts of `nsize`
      # e.g. [1,2,3,4,5] with nsize = 2 will split into ([1,2], [3,4], [5])
      ilist   = np.array_split(idx, round(idx.shape[0]/nsize + 0.5))
      dflist += ilist

  return [idf.loc[idx].copy(deep=True) for idx in dflist]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.hstack((np.random.choice(np.arange(1,3), 10).reshape(10, -1), np.random.rand(10,3))), columns=['id', 'a', 'b', 'c'])

df = df.astype({'id': np.int64})

split(df, 'id', 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a great problem, you can use this (data is the DataFrame here):

```
# Create subsets of size 30 for the DataFrame
subsets = list(range(0, len(data), 30))

# Create start cutoffs for subsets of the DataFrame
start_cutoff = subsets

# Create end cutoffs for subsets of the DataFrame
end_cutoff = subsets[1:] +  [len(data)]

# Zip the start cutoffs and end cutoffs into a List of Cutoffs
cutoffs = list(zip(start_cutoff, end_cutoff))

# List containing Splitted Dataframes
list_dfs = [data.iloc[cutoff[0]: cutoff[-1]] for cutoff in cutoffs]

# convert list to string DFs
string_dfs = [df.to_string(header=False, index=False, index_names=False).split('\n') for df in list_dfs]

final_df_list = [','.join(ele.split()) for string_df in string_dfs for ele in string_df]
```

Now you can access the DataFrames by:

```
 print(final_df_list[0])
 print(final_df_list[1])
```